# Python Matplotlib How to plot a line chart in weekly intervale

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am working in a project where I need to plot data and  into a line chart. The problem is that i don't have the X values i have just the Y values 
here is the list of the value that i want to plot :

```
     testlist =['278264', '322823', '287298', '295212', '299174', '277271',  '352717', '583802', '1167864', '1622965', '1759879', '1779014', '174791']
```

the result that i am loking for is something like this screenshot [image]

but with my code i am geting this result [image]

i tried the following code but i am having an error :ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

```
testlist =['278264', '322823', '287298', '295212', '299174', '277271', '352717', '583802', '1167864', '1622965', '1759879', '1779014', '174791']
last = len(testlist)
for i in range (0,last):
    intValue= int(testlist[i])
    testlist[i]=intValue

x = [1,7,13,19,25,31]
y = testlist


plt.plot(x,y)
```

any Idea on how can i solve this issue ?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you got an error because you have 13 y values and 7 x values.
Usually points are **(x, y)** right? So you need to have `len(x) == len(y)`.

Where did you got the screenshot you want? Can you retrieve its data? As you said, you don't have the x axis, but you have to get it, otherwise the x axis will be **arbitrary**, make sense isn't it?

Regards,
Paul